# How to clear IIS Windows Authentication cache in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am using Windows Authentication in my Web Application its working well.. now I need to support Sign As different user, for that I need to clear existing windows authentication cache to force to ask credential once again.

Can any one help me?.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It stores both certificate data and also user passwords.

Open a command prompt, or enter the following in the run command

```
rundll32.exe keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr
```

Windows 7 will open window to delete all stored values.

See this if it helps you

http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/A_448-How-to-DELETE-Windows-Local-Domain-Cached-Credentials.html

http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=825

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do it by C#

Comment: Have added couple of links which will give you idea about how we can do